# asp.net page vertical splitter panel - msdn style

Tags: asp.net, ajax, splitter

I have downloaded the [Splitter Panel Ajaxian ASP.NET WebControl](http://splitterpanel.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. This is exactly what i need to implement in the project.

The problem is there is no good documentation available and I am not able to access the controls inside the `LeftPane` and `RightPane` tags.

Can you recommend any sample code or articles or other documentation available to access controls that are placed in the left and the right panes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the latest release:

```
Label label1 = (Label)SplitterPanel1.FindControl("label1");
```

Or, for the right pane, do this:

```
Label label1 = (Label)SplitterPanel1.RightOwner.FindControl("label1");
```

For left pane you can do this:

```
Label label1 = (Label)SplitterPanel1.LeftOwner.FindControl("label1");
```